# JSON.parse does not work

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP function that simply calls the database for an array of results and then outputs it as a JSON object like so:

**PHP:**

```
function getSubscriptionDetails(){
    $subscription = $this->client_model->getSubscription($this->user->info->ID);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($subscription);
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
    maxDenomination: "100",
    startDate: "2018-01-19 19:44:41",
    endDate: "2018-02-19 19:44:41",
    subscriptionID: "8",
    packageID: "1",
    packageName: "Silver"
}
```

My goal is to be able to use this in my javascript AJAX call but when I try and run `JSON.parse` on it, it says its not valid.

From what I gathered, valid JSON is supposed to have quoted key names as well. I glanced through [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) but couldn't see anything that enabled this.

Am I missing something here? I am not manually creating the array so I can't quote them myself, was hoping it was just a option I could pass with the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

your result a json object you dnt need to parse it if it is a json string you need to prase it

to get the value of maxDenomination try the below

```
var a = {
    maxDenomination: "100",
    startDate: "2018-01-19 19:44:41",
    endDate: "2018-02-19 19:44:41",
    subscriptionID: "8",
    packageID: "1",
    packageName: "Silver"
}

console.log(a.maxDenomination);
```